# Basics.vo contains library Basics and not library Metalib.Basics

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, coqide

I am getting the error "Basics.vo contains library Basics
and not library Metalib.Basics" in CoqIDE 4.5. I am following Software Foundations and importing Basics as 'Require Export Basics.'. Also I compiled the Basics using the same CoqIDE. In the past I was using CoqIDE 4.2 and this worked fine in CoqIDE 4.2. Now I switched to CoqIDE 4.5, deleted previously compiled Basics.vo and compiled again.
Can someone please help me in that?

I have tried deleting the previously compiled Basics.v. Also tried restarting CoqIDE multiple times.

```
Print LoadPath.
Require Export Basics.

Theorem plus_n_O_firsttry : forall n:nat, n = n+0.

Proof.
   intros n.
   simpl.
Abort.
```

Comment: We might need some information to help you. What is your operating system? Are you using the latest version of Software Foundations? Did you unzip its files into their own directory? Did you ever download the metalib (https://github.com/plclub/metalib)?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I am using Ubuntu 18.04. I did not download files from the repository, instead I created the files from scratch. Also I never downloaded metalib. Please feel free to ask if anything is required.

Comment: Try downloading the SF sources from https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/index.html, unzipping them, and hitting `make` at the top-level.